# Push notification in Cordova app for android and ios

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I need to set push notification into my app. Notification must work even if app was closed. How can I do that?
I found few services that provides notifications, but I didnt understand how to work with it

Comment: what sort of services ? Background or web

Comment: background service

Comment: That is not necessary to have app running in background. Push notifications works even app is killed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use phonegap's push plugin.

Open command prompt go to the project folder and type following command:

**cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="YOUR SENDER ID"**

You will get SENDER_ID in your google developer console project

Comment: It works for iOS also.Just add random senderID for iOS instead of actual one.

Comment: yes it will work for both iOS and android.It will also work when the appp is in background or closed.

Comment: Can anyone please write simple code example on php?